# Editing a question that already has been edited

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

If question has already been edited, there's option that I can still edit the answer. My question is, will my proposed suggestion will get approved even when respective question/answer was edited by person who have better reputation than me?

Comment: It depends on the timing. Sometimes a person who has edit privileges will knock your suggested edit out because it will overwrite yours. It all depends on who submitted when, and at what revision.

Comment: @gunr2171: That's what i want to know, my suggested edit will get knocked out on basis of what? is it because other person proposed better suggestion or is it the reputation of the person.

Comment: see [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/165773) "You submit a suggested edit at the same time as the original poster or a 2000+ rep user (20000+ in the case of tag wikis) or any moderator (in other words, anyone who has full edit privileges over the specific post). In that case, your suggested edit will be rejected by Community in favor of the fully privileged edit. Since the Community user does not provide a message when such an edit is rejected, it may appear as though the system has rejected your edit immediately..."

Comment: In short it depends on reputation and privilege, Am I right?